# OCaml - mutable fields

Tags: ocaml, mutable

I have a question:
What is it mutable field ?
Is it connected with reference ?
If I can create mutable "without" creating record
Thanks in advcane!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, references are implemented in terms of mutable fields:
a reference is just a record with a single (mutable) field named
`contents`, as you can see in your toplevel:

```
# let x = ref 1;;
val x : int ref = {contents = 1}
# x.contents;;
- : int = 1
# x.contents <- 2;;
- : unit = ()
# !x;;
- : int = 2
```

The main way to get mutable fields is to use records, and it is the
way you should prefer. Objects have mutable instance variables. You
can also get the equivalent of references by using one-element arrays.